# Only repeats 1 to 10 pages when I crawl Python(Blog crawling)

Tags: python, csv, web-crawler

I want to crawl Naver blog with the following code, only posts 1 to 10 on the first page will be crawled. 11 ~ 20, 21 ~ 30 .... How do I edit to continue crawling

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

BASE_URL = "https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=post&sm=tab_pge&query=%ED%99%94%EC%A0%95%EC%B2%9C&st=sim&date_option=8&date_from=20160101&date_to=20161231&dup_remove=1&post_blogurl=&post_blogurl_without=&srchby=all&nso=p%3Afrom20160101to20161231&ie=utf8&start="

f = open("park01.csv", 'w', newline='')
wr =csv.writer(f)

for i in range(100):
        URL_with_page_num = BASE_URL + str(1 + i*10)
        response = requests.get(BASE_URL)
        response.status_code
        print (response.status_code)
        dom = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        post_elements = dom.select("li.sh_blog_top")

        for post_element in post_elements:
            title_element = post_element.select_one("a.sh_blog_title")
            passage_element = post_element.select_one("dd.sh_blog_passage")
            title = title_element.text
            url = title_element.get("href")
            passage = passage_element.text
            data=[title, url, passage]
            wr.writerow(data)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is in below code -

```
for i in range(100):
    URL_with_page_num = BASE_URL + str(1 + i*10)
    response = requests.get(BASE_URL)
```

put `URL_with_page_num` in place of `BASE_URL` in last line of above code

```
response = requests.get(URL_with_page_num)
```

Comment: @윤승용 Please accept as answer if your problem is resolved.